# Orchard: Displaying only a single content item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, orchardcms

I want to be able to display a content item of a certain type and only that content item i.e. no shapes that are not part of said item.

I have tried creating a controller method with a {Themed(false)] attribute, or returning a partial view. Both of these do almost exactly what I want, except that these don't include any scripts or styles associated with the View I'm trying to display.

My current attempt look like this:

### Controller method:

```
[Themed(false)]
public ActionResult DisplayBare(int id) {
    var contentItem = _contentManager.Get(id, VersionOptions.Published);
    dynamic model = _contentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItem);
    return View( (object)model);
}
```

### The `DisplayBare` view:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    @Display(Model)
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when the display View of an item includes `Script.Require`,  `Script.Include` and `Script.Foot` directives, the scripts do not show up in the Html.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Are your styles/scripts in your theme?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by snooping around Orchard sources:

Using this view to display my content item gives me exactly what i want:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        @{
            Style.Include("Site.css");
            var content = Display(Model);
        }
        @Display.Metas()
        @Display.HeadScripts()
        @Display.HeadLinks()
        @Display.StyleSheetLinks()
    </head>
<body>
    @content
    @Display.FootScripts()
</body>
</html>
```